# gdb can't be properly installed in Mac Sierra

Tags: python, c, macos, gdb

I tried everything I can find about installing gdb, but still could not make it work.

Here is how I install and run gdb:

1. install gdb with `brew install gdb`
2. then it tells me to do the following

   (experiment3.5)  ->brew install gdb
    Updating Homebrew...
    ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gdb-
    8.0.1.sierra.bottle.tar
    Already downloaded: /Users/Natsume/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gdb-
    8.0.1.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
    ==> Pouring gdb-8.0.1.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
    ==> Caveats
    gdb requires special privileges to access Mach ports.
    You will need to codesign the binary. For instructions, see:
     https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin

   On 10.12 (Sierra) or later with SIP, you need to run this:

   `echo "set startup-with-shell off" >> ~/.gdbinit`
3. I did finish these two steps. I did the codesign task by following exact instruction [here](https://medium.com/@royalstream/how-to-install-and-codesign-gdb-on-os-x-el-capitan-aab3d1172e95)
4. everything goes smoothly. however, when I ran the following code, I still get the same error message

I ran `gdb python test.py` and received following message

```
(experiment3.5)  ->gdb python signal_test.py
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from python...
warning: `/Users/travis/miniconda3/conda-bld/python_1494603145199/work/Python-3.5.3/Programs/python.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> No module named libpython:
"/Users/Natsume/Documents/shendusuipian/pytorch/raw_pytorch/60min_intro/signal_test.py" is not a core dump: File format not recognized
```

5. then I did download `libpython.py`, but I don't know what to do with it.
6. I don't have such folder `/Users/travis/miniconda3/conda-bld/python_1494603145199/work/Python-3.5.3/Programs/python.o'` as stated in the warning message above

**Update**
I have tried to follow [the steps here](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3689), I directly used the `gdb8.01.tar.gz` downloaded through `brew install gdb`, but I got error message below.

```
Focus on one: /Users/Natsume/Desktop/src/gdb/8.0.1
 ->./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/usr/local
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
Focus on one: /Users/Natsume/Desktop/src/gdb/8.0.1
 ->ls
COPYING         README          share
ChangeLog       bin
INSTALL_RECEIPT.json    include
Focus on one: /Users/Natsume/Desktop/src/gdb/8.0.1
 ->
```

**update**
I ran the code from the link above, and installed, configured gdb8.0, however, I don't have a folder as `$HOME/opt/usr/local`, but only `/opt/usr/local`. Therefore, although `./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/usr/local` ran through, but I still can't run `codesign -f -s  "gdb-cert"  <gnat_install_prefix>/bin/gdb`, as there is no `$HOME/opt/usr/local`.

**update**

exactly forllowing the link above, I can install `gdb 8.0`, but I can't run `gfortran`,

```
(experiment3.5)  ->gfortran
-bash: gfortran: command not found
```

nor can I run `gdb python test.py` with success:

```
(experiment3.5)  ->gdb --args python signal_test.py
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from python...
warning: `/Users/travis/miniconda3/conda-bld/python_1494603145199/work/Python-3.5.3/Programs/python.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> No module named libpython:
```

**Update**
through [this link](http://droettboom.com/blog/2015/11/20/gdb-python-extensions/) to build `~/.gdbinit` can get rid of the error of `No module named libpython` is solved; however, the warning or bigger problem is still present

> warning: `/Users/travis/miniconda3/conda-bld/python_1494603145199/work/Python-3.5.3/Programs/python.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
>       (no debugging symbols found)...done.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spent quite some time on this one. You need to compile it from sources.

Take a look here:

[Running GDB in macOS sierra](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3689)

It worked for me ;)

Just one note, make sure to code sign it! Notes can be found here: [Codesigning the Debugger](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gnat_ugn_unw/Codesigning-the-Debugger.html)

Update:

***for python stuff, take a look here***

http://unconj.ca/blog/setting-up-gdb-for-debugging-python-on-os-x.html

***as for gdb itself***

it should be enough to test it following way

```
// simple.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello\n");
  return 0;
}
```

and then

```
# assuming that gdb is signed
cc -g -o simple simple.c
gdb ./simple
```

***Update - System Integrity Protection***

When it comes to some areas (e.g. /usr/bin) you won't have access there due to the fact that System Integrity Protection is on. You need to turn it off:

```
# You need to boot to Recovery OS in a first place (before you call csrutil)
> csrutil disable

# you can also use another location as output
> lipo /usr/bin/python -thin x86_64 -output ~/python64
```

Take a look here when it comes to details of [System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html).

Comment: thanks a lot for this quick reply, and I will give a try now

Comment: I tried but got error message saying `./configure: no such file or dir`, where did I do wrong? I have updated the details in my question above

Comment: I followed your codes exactly, install gdb 8.0, but still not working, please my latest update. Do you know why?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will keep trying! by the way, atom gdb debugger seems work again. I am trying to solve the python issue with your link.

Comment: the python link is not working for me. the problem seems to be `(experiment3.5)  ->lipo /usr/bin/python -thin x86_64 -output /usr/bin/python64
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't create output file: /usr/bin/python64 (Operation not permitted)`

Comment: Thank you so much! The update of your answer helped! it works now!

Comment: .oOo. Cool! .oOo.